# getting data out of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i would like to get data out of this multidimensional-array:

```
Array
(
    [result] => success
    [source] => getLatestConsoleLogs
    [success] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [time] => 1324301613
                    [line] => 2011-12-19 17:33:33 [INFO] [JSONAPI] [API Call] 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1: method=getLatestConsoleLogs?args=[]

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [time] => 1324301613
                    [line] => 2011-12-19 17:33:33 [INFO] [JSONAPI] [API Call] 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1: method=getLatestConsoleLogs?args=[]

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [time] => 1324301613
                    [line] => 2011-12-19 17:33:33 [INFO] [JSONAPI] [API Call] 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1: method=getLatestConsoleLogs?args=[]

                )

            )
    )
```

i would be nice, if somehow it could be extracted to div`s. thanks.

Comment: What you want to get out out the array?

Comment: actually it`ll be best, if I could get all data out :)

Comment: I would recommend you having some time in learning basic php, rather than using stackoverflow users as your tutors.

Comment: well, I know basic PHP, but I allways have problems with arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a normal foreach loop like this:

```
$successes = $array['success'] /* where $array is the variable holding the result */
foreach($successes as $success) {
    echo "<div>Time: " . $success['time'] . " - Line: " . $success['line'] . "</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can so [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to convert your array to JSON and then use javascript to place those in appropriate div's

OR if you want to do it on server side, you can check this

http://www.terrawebdesign.com/multidimensional.php

Comment: then whats coming to your way? you can simply place them! what's stopping you?

Comment: then I have updated the answer for you, check if this works for you!